# How can I require two fingers to scroll between pages of a UIPageViewController using the ‘scroll’ transition style?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am developing an application for iOS 6 which will not ever be submitted to the App Store.

I’m trying to use `UIPageViewController` to allow the user to swipe left-to-right between four different view controllers. This works great but in order to allow normal single-finger interaction with each view controller, I’d like to require two fingers to swipe between pages of the `UIPageViewController`.

The documentation suggests I should be able to do this by customising the `UIGestureRecognizer` objects found in the `gestureRecognizers` property of my `UIPageViewController`. However, this property seems to be an empty array when the `transitionStyle` is set to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

If I change the `transitionStyle` to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` the property contains `UIGestureRecognizer` objects and I can customise them at will.

Is there any (documented or otherwise) way to achieve what I want using the scroll transition type?

Comment: it seems a bug to me, the UIPageViewController should have at least a gestureRecognizer because it's responding to gestures. I just tested and you are right, it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved that with this code if it solves you the problem. UIPageViewController with scroll transition is implemented with a UIScrollView that is a child of the main view of the controller, UIScrollViewController has a panGesture property used to process the touches of the pan so:

```
for (UIView* view in [editor.view subviews]) {
    if ([view  isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        UIScrollView* scrollView = (UIScrollView*)view;
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    }
}
```

And that solves the problem!

Answer (score 2):

UIPageViewController.h has the following comment:

```
// Only populated if transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl'.
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *gestureRecognizers;
```

Not sure why it's not in the docs.